# Python Quadratic Equation Class

Tags: python, class, quadratic

I am currently creating a class in python to make a quadratic equation. I wrote down a discriminant function within the class, and I'm trying to call on it within the roots function, however, I'm not sure how to do it for certain. I am getting an attribute error.

AttributeError: 'QuadraticEquation' object has no attribute 'discrimiant'

```
def discriminant(self):
    return ((self.b)**2) - (4 * self.a * self.c)

def root1(self):
    if self.discrimiant() < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return (-self.b + math.sqrt(self.discriminant())) / (2 * self.a)
def root2(self):
    if self.discrimiant() < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return (-self.b - math.sqrt(self.discriminant())) / (2 * self.a)
```

Comment: that looks good

Comment: What's the problem that you're having? `self.discriminant()` should be the correct call?

Comment: getting AttributeError: 'QuadraticEquation' object has no attribute 'discrimiant'

Comment: Fix ur typos and report back. FYI a neg discriminant means no real roots. There may be complex roots.

Comment: You have a spelling error :) `discriminant`, not `discrimiant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in your code. `discriminant`, not `discrimiant`. Here is a working code -

```
class QuadraticEquation:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def discriminant(self):
        return ((self.b)**2) - (4 * self.a * self.c)

    def root1(self):
        if self.discriminant() < 0:
            return None
        else:
            return (-self.b + math.sqrt(self.discriminant())) / (2 * self.a)
    def root2(self):
        if self.discriminant() < 0:
            return None
        else:
            return (-self.b - math.sqrt(self.discriminant())) / (2 * self.a)

a = QuadraticEquation(1,2,3)
print a.root1()
print a.root2()
print a.discriminant()
```